# How can i write join query in android sqlite?

Tags: android

Hi, I am new to android. I want to write query for join in sqlite. My code is -

```
public Cursor SearchCategory(SQLiteDatabase db){
        //return  db.query("category_master", null, "status = 'Active'", null, null, null, null);

        String Category_Sql = " select category_master.*,count(*) as cnt from product_master " +
                            "   left join category_master on product_master.category_id = category_master.category_id " +
                            "   where category_master.status = 'Active' group by category_master.category_id having cnt > 0 ";
        return db.query(Category_Sql);
    }
```

but it generate error. Where am I wrong?

Comment: You can refer to [this post](http://www.anddev.org/sqlite_join_problem-t877.html).

Answer (score 0):

It would have helped more if you could cite the error description.

Try running the query first in [Portable SQLite explorer](http://portableapps.com/apps/development/sqlite_database_browser_portable)

Answer (score 0):

you can use rawQuery

```
db.rawQuery("Select a.column1,b.column1 FROM table1 a JOIN table2 b ON a._id=b._id", null);
```

it should work